# How to find out which panel in split container is clicked on mouse click?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I am using split containers in my application. One parent split container. There are three split containers in panel2 of parent split container.

Now when I click on one of the panel of split container embedded in panel2 of parent container, how to find that which containers which panel is clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try subscribing all of the panel's to use the same click event.  The sender would be the SplitterPanel class, which will have a Parent property (hidden from IDE but it's there) that will be the SplitContainer:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  splitContainer1.Panel1.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer1.Panel2.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer2.Panel1.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer2.Panel2.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer3.Panel1.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer3.Panel2.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer4.Panel1.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
  splitContainer4.Panel2.MouseClick += Panel_MouseClick;
}

void Panel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  SplitterPanel sp = sender as SplitterPanel;
  SplitContainer sc = sp.Parent as SplitContainer;
  MessageBox.Show(sc.Name + " - " + sp.Tag.ToString());
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I entered a 1 or a 2 in the tag property of each panel since the sub-panels used in the SplitContainer do not use the Name proprety.

Comment: Thank you very much your code has solved my other issues also.!!

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` property of your event handler is the clicked panel.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    //sender is the panel which has just been clicked, cast it.
}
```